# Get ninject factory extension to allow factory parameters be passed to dependencies

Tags: c#, ninject, ninject-2, ninject-extensions

Using the Ninject Factory extension, you can automatically generate factories, and let the factory pass parameters to the class' constructor. The following test passes:

```
public interface IBar
{
    int Foo { get; }
}

public class Bar : IBar
{
    int _foo;
    public Bar(int foo) { _foo = foo; }
    public int Foo { get { return _foo; } }
}

public interface IBarFactory
{
    IBar CreateTest(int foo);
}

[Test]
public void ExecuteTest()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();
    kernel.Bind<IBar>().To<Bar>();
    kernel.Bind<IBarFactory>().ToFactory();
    var factory = kernel.Get<IBarFactory>();
    var actual = factory.CreateTest(42);
    Assert.That(actual, Is.InstanceOf<Bar>());
}
```

However, in my particular problem, I would like it to pass the factory arguments to a dependency of the class I'm constructing, not the class itself, like this:

```
public interface IBarContainer
{
    IBar Bar { get; }
}

public class BarContainer : IBarContainer
{
    IBar _bar;
    public BarContainer(IBar bar) { _bar = bar; }
    public IBar Bar { get { return _bar; } }
}

public interface ITestContainerFactory
{
    IBarContainer CreateTestContainer(int foo);
}

[Test]
public void ExecuteTestContainer()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();
    kernel.Bind<IBar>().To<Bar>();
    kernel.Bind<IBarContainer>().To<BarContainer>();
    kernel.Bind<ITestContainerFactory>().ToFactory();
    var factory = kernel.Get<ITestContainerFactory>();
    var actual = factory.CreateTestContainer(42);
    Assert.That(actual.Bar, Is.InstanceOf<Bar>());
}
```

This test fails with the message:

> Ninject.ActivationException : Error activating int No matching
>   bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable. Activation
>   path:
>     3) Injection of dependency int into parameter foo of constructor of type Bar
>     2) Injection of dependency IBar into parameter bar of constructor of type BarContainer
>     1) Request for IBarContainer

Is there a way to make the factory figure out that I want to use the passed 'foo' argument when resolving the 'Bar' dependency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From version 3.2.0 of Ninject.Extensions.Factory this is supported natively, using:

```
Ninject.Extensions.Factory.TypeMatchingArgumentInheritanceInstanceProvider
```

You can use it like this:

```
kernel.Bind<IxxxFactory>()
   .ToFactory(() => new TypeMatchingArgumentInheritanceInstanceProvider());
```

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/blob/master/src/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/Factory/TypeMatchingArgumentInheritanceInstanceProvider.cs), it's based on the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11235383/921090).

Comment: Thank you for this piece of information! This should be the accepted answer as it uses built in functionality.

Answer (score 5):

Hy,
The default instance provider does not use constructor arguments which are inherited. You can change this behavior by writing your own instance provider like the following:

```
public class CustomInstanceProvider : StandardInstanceProvider {
    protected override ConstructorArgument[] 
        GetConstructorArguments(MethodInfo methodInfo, object[] arguments) 
        {
            var parameters = methodInfo.GetParameters();
            var constructorArguments = 
                new ConstructorArgument[parameters.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
            {
                constructorArguments[i] = 
                    new ConstructorArgument
                        (parameters[i].Name, arguments[i], true);
            }
            return constructorArguments;
        }
}
```

Then you only have to instruct ninject to use your own instead of the provided.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I believe that this Ninject Wiki article has a good example ( [Factory interface](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki/Factory-interface) ) on how to use the new .ToFactory() binding extension, and how to get those generated factories to even create objects who's constructors have parameters.